# Prediction of stock price using Date time

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, linear-regression

excuse me, I am new to using linear regression. I want to ask how to overcome the problem I faced, I tried to predict the stock price using the closing price with time/date. but I have an error that the value at Y (stock price) cannot be processed with the value of X (date). Are there any suggestions for solving my problem?

[this is my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zf8Mo.png)

[and this is my regression linear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsW64.png)

[and this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtS9d.png)

Thank You.

Comment: I suggest converting the date to "days since December 1", so that the dates become numbers. I also suggest posting text data as text, and not as images.

Comment: thank you very much sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linear regression can work only with numbers, so I would suggest you to construct new input features based on original datetime. 
E.g:
- Number of month
- Day of month
- Year
- Hour of day

If you wish, you can also construct more advanced features. For example if you feel like stock price can depend on weekend, you can engeneer features like:
- Is weekend (1 if true / 0 if false)
- Is holiday (1 if true / 0 if false)
Etc.